# Change tab programmatically on JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a navbar (bellow) and I would like to change tabs using Javascript, found no documentation to help me and a lot of broken code online, I would appreciate some help here.

Test case: the tab has page-1 initially selected, I would like to change to page-2 using javascript.

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
<div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#page-1" data-ajax="false" class="ui-btn-active">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-2" data-ajax="false">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-3" data-ajax="false">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-4" data-ajax="false">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-5" data-ajax="false">5</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Tested Code:**

```
var index = $('#tabs a[href="#page-2"]').parent().index();
$('#tabs').tabs('select', index);
```

Throws:

```
Error: no such method 'select' for tabs widget instance
```

**After the solution I came up with these functions:**

```
function changeNavPagePrevious(tabControl) {
    if ($("#" + tabControl + " .ui-tabs-active").prev().length > 0) {
        if ($("#" + tabControl + " .ui-tabs-active").prev().children().length > 0) {
        changeNavPage(tabControl, $("#" + tabControl + " .ui-tabs-active").prev().children().eq(0).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
        }
    }
}

function changeNavPageNext(tabControl) {
    if ($("#" + tabControl + " .ui-tabs-active").next().length > 0) {
        if ($("#" + tabControl + " .ui-tabs-active").next().children().length > 0) {
            changeNavPage(tabControl, $("#" + tabControl + " .ui-tabs-active").next().children().eq(0).attr("href").replace("#", ""));
        }
    }
}

function changeNavPage(tabControl, newPage)
{
    $("#" + tabControl + " .ui-btn-active").eq(0).removeClass("ui-btn-active").removeClass('ui-tabs-active').removeClass("ui-state-active");
    $('#tabs a[href="#' + newPage + '"]').addClass('ui-btn-active');

    var index = $('#' + tabControl + ' a[href="#' + newPage + '"]').parent().index();
    $("#" + tabControl).tabs("option", "active", index);
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/aX7L9/

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>     
        <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="tabs" class="tabs">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#one" data-theme="a">one</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#two" data-theme="a">two</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax-content.html" data-theme="a" data-ajax="false">three</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="one" class="ui-content">
                    <h1>First tab contents</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="two" class="ui-content">
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function () {
    pageId = $('body').pagecontainer('getActivePage').prop('id'); 

    if (pageId === 'index') {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".tabs").tabs( "option", "active", 1 );
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

jQuery Mobile uses jQuery UI tab widget so find everything you need **[here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/)**.

Answer (score 4):

Why not simply use

```
$('a[href="#page-2"]').trigger("click");
```

For me that did the trick.

Comment: Because (1) This will do a lot more than just change the tab; and (2) it's a lot less readable

Comment: Back in the day when I tried this approach I remember there were a few issues but I don't recall exactly what it was.