# How to update navbar after reassigning new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to change the target tab on the fly

```
$('#tab0').attr('href', '#four');
$('#tab0').text('Logout');
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="settingsPage">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a id="tab0" href="#one" class="ui-btn-active">Tab One</a></li>
                    <li><a id="tab1" href="#two">Tab Two</a></li>
                    <li><a id="tab2" href="#three">Tab Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="one" style="display: none" class="ui-body-d ui-content">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
            <div id="two" style="display: none" class="ui-body-d ui-content">bbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
            <div id="three" style="display: none" class="ui-body-d ui-content">cccccccccccc</div>
            <div id="four" style="display: none" class="ui-body-d ui-content">Not supposed to show this now</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would expect first tab to change navbar item AND content of tab.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v7z6fj05/17/)

As you see the first navbar item name is changing indeed, but content doesn't. How to refresh without reloading the whole page?

Comment: So you'd want `#four` to show "Not supposed to show this now" after the `setTimeout`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for typo, in demo it is #four.

Answer (score 1):

The mobile tabs use the same API as [jQuery UI tabs](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/).

Can do something like:

```
$('#tab0').attr('href', '#four').text('Logout');

$('#tabs').tabs("refresh");
$('#one').hide();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rmk6o6ur/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: this works, but `remove` will cause headache, since I then need to add it again. The idea behind was to have number of tabs, then dynamically reassign to each tab and refresh navbar.

Comment: so change it to `hide()` instead of `remove()`

Comment: But I wonder why `$('#tabs').trigger('create')` or `$('#tabs').trigger('refresh')` doesn't work... Even on page they are not working.

Comment: Still need to hide. No way to rebuild tabs without keeping track of what to hide and unhide, only based on href.

Comment: Sure ... because you have more content than matches the tabs themselves. Can adapt it a bit more to use one selector string to do both if that helps ... get the current href and use it to match to id to hide. Or hide all and then refresh

Comment: I would appreciate it.

Comment: Need more details on what your higher level objective is to make this more robust.

Comment: Each tab item have a state. For example `tab0` item can have `notLoggedIn`, `loginInProgress`, `loggedIn`. When a click triggered on tab item, the state(s) may change asynchronously. The tab should show content according to current state of item. Initially tab also should render content according to state.

Comment: Maybe you need a `states` object  that contains tabs info for various states. Then iterate that object when state changes. Can store the content in that object also if needed

Comment: Tabs info is actually the id of tab and id of content for every state, like a rotary switch. The problem here is how to apply each state to each tab without doing hide/show work, just by leveraging jQM. I came from manually show/hide divs to jQM tabs with hope that it can do this heavy duty work. Looks to me pretty common pattern what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I've got an idea - what if I hide all tab content divs, then `refresh`? I've hid them by applying an empty css class. Looks like it works and `refresh` is taking care of un-hiding the current content.

Comment: Really not sure how complex your situation is but here's one idea. For some reason has a bug for button styles but they all work http://jsfiddle.net/vy2k8qfz/

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to go back to tab zero, here is the quick and dirty

```
setTimeout(function(){

    $('#tab0').attr('href', '#four');
    $('#tab0').text('Logout');

    // some update should happen here to 
    $('#tab0').trigger("click");

}, 9000);
```

Comment: Actually it probably won't work, because the code where I am substituting tab is located in `click` event, so it will be some dead loop...

Comment: it does work as for as it goes. I ran it in your jsfiddle.  Note, for no reason in particular, I changed it to 9 seconds.

Comment: Unless I miss something, it still shows the content "aaaaaa..." after the timeout. http://jsfiddle.net/v7z6fj05/20/

Comment: The code to change is `$('#tab0').attr('href', '#four')` which is now pointing to different tab content.

Comment: That will not work. Behind the scenes, a tabs object is created the paths are already created. Changing the link afterwards will not work.  Try making all four tabs at once but marking one inactive. Then you can make it active on "logout"

Comment: also, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023096/change-tab-programmatically-on-jquery-mobile